# Why app insight generate _MS.links column for event hub dependency telemetry?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring, appinsights

I added event hub to my application and App Insight started to emit telemetry with for event dependency. One of the column in this dependency is _MS.links causing downstream workflows to fail due to column name.

Why app insight emits column with _MS. prefix?

Answer (score 2):

`customDimensions["_MS.links"]` is the "Operation links" used alongside Operation Id (`operation_Id`), Parent Id (`operation_ParentId`) and Id (`id`) for Application Insights to correlate telemetry. See [Understanding operation IDs & operation links when working with Event Hubs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cse/2021/05/13/observability-for-event-stream-processing-with-azure-functions-event-hubs-and-application-insights/#2-understanding-operation-ids-operation-links-when-working-with-event-hubs) for more info on that.

Comment: Why the column is referenced as _MS.links instead of Operation links?

Answer (score 0):

Names with special characters should be referenced as `x["y"]` or `x['y']` (instead of `x.y`), in this case: `customDimensions["_MS.links"]`, as demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/serverless/event-hubs-functions/observability#end-to-end-latency-for-an-event)